# Remove duplicate keys from array?

Tags: php, arrays

I have the following array:

```
Array
(
    [https://i.imgur.com/UYK4Agz.png] => dummy2
    [https://i.imgur.com/UYK4Agz.png] => dummy2
    [https://i.imgur.com/vyGHgZN.jpg] => dummy2
    [https://i.imgur.com/vyGHgZN.jpg] => dummy1
)
```

Id like to remove all duplicate keys. This is the expected result:

```
Array
(
    [https://i.imgur.com/UYK4Agz.png] => dummy2
    [https://i.imgur.com/vyGHgZN.jpg] => dummy2
)
```

Tried using `array_unique` but it only works for values.

Also took a look at other posts here but they all talk about way bigger arrays, im really confused.

Sorry for the noobish question, please point me to the right function I should use!

Thanks SO xx

Comment: Array can't contain duplicate keys.

Comment: it is impossible to have duplicate keys, unless there are hidden characters in your keys. Try to run a hashing function on both keys and see if they are the same.

Comment: ah well.. thats not breathtaking.

Comment: Just noticed how they kept disapearing, i tought the "duplicate" keys were the issue. Thanks alot.